# How do I modify spring boot security redirect on login to not redirect back to login?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We have a spring boot application configured as an oauth2 client.  Occasionally, we have people where their browser sends a request like this to the application:

https://app/login?code=XXX&state=ZZZ

The code and state were cached from a previous authentication attempt and are invalid right now.

Spring security sees that this person is not authenticated, so it redirects them to /login which then does the whole oauth2 authentication but then after they are authenticated, spring security sends them back to /login?code=XXX&state=ZZZ because that was their original request.  When that happens, it tries to validate the code and state but fails and sends them to an error page.  This is a problem when supporting the app because the user is authentcated.

Is there a way to change the logic of the the storing of the initial request so that if it is /login we can replace that with /?  There might be other solutions we haven't thought of.  Any help would be appreciated.

Our app is currently using Spring boot 2 but I've tried this with the latest version of Spring boot 3 and it is still an issue.  We have been unable to change the browser behavior so would like to solve this on the server if possible.

Here is our configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/info", "/static/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .csrf();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to avoid redirect only sometimes (so SpringSecurity's `defaultSuccessUrl` is not an option).

If so, you can implement your own AuthenricationSuccessHandler like this:

```
...
.successHandler(
    (request, response, authentication) -> {
        if (request.getRequestURI().equals("/your/invalid/path"))
            response.sendRedirect("/");
    }
...
```

Comment: I don't see anyplace where successHandler can go.  It seems that only works if you have a login form.   I added our configuration to the original question.

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to set the `loginPage`, just the `loginProcessingUrl` (by default it's "/llogin"). How are you authenticating?

Comment: We are using oauth2.  Sorry, stackoverflow wouldn't let me put that in the subject of the post.  There is no local login page with oauth2.  If you would like to try oauth2 authentication, here's a url to a project you can use: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/